# How to make internal links in org-mode case insensitive

Tags: org-mode

If I have a heading called "heading1", I can link to it within the same `org` file with `[[heading1]]`, but cannot link to it with `[[Heading1]]`. Is there a way to make links case insensitive?

Comment: The searches work in a case insensitive way inside of my org test buffer. They also are not affected by the `case-fold-search` variable. Does the link not work for you inside of an org mode buffer, or you have that problem in some exported document?

Comment: I am talking about org-mode buffer. I am not talking about search, I am asking about following internal org links and case sensitivity. Please original question and let me know if I there is something I need to clarify about it.

Comment: internal links are implemented as a search in the buffer (q.v. http://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-links.html). Contrary to your tests, in my own org buffers a link like [[heading1]] works in a case-insensitive way... so this is why I was asking. Maybe something in your config makes the search case sensitive.

Comment: I tried starting emacs with -Q option to avoid loading any custom configuration. 
When I use `C-c C-o`  with `[[heading1]]`, the cursor jumps to `heading1`. When I use `C-c C-o` with `[[Heading1]]`, I get prompted with `No match - create this as a new heading? (y or n)`
My emacs version is 24.3.1 (running on Ubuntu). My org version 7.9.3f.

Comment: Ok... it is due to your

Comment: Ok... it is due to your Org version. I tested now with your same emacs version and default org. There I get the same behavior. Emacs 24.3.1 with the org version 8.3.3 from MELPA shows the behavior you want and jumps to links in a case insensitive way. You should upgrade Org... even more so, since Org >=8 brings a plethora of improvements and a completely new exporter (Bastien just posted the release of 8.3.4 btw).

Comment: That was it. I installed org from MELPA, restarted emacs and internal links started working as I wanted (case insensitive). Thank you @dfeich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @dfeich suggestion I installed org from ELPA and internal links became case insensitive.

The version that I installed from ELPA is 8.3.4 (20160222). The built in version that I had before was 7.9.3f.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [internal link](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Internal-links)
section in the Org manual, it doesn't look like it is possible. You can,
however, use `[[heading1][Heading1]]` if you want to make the *description* a
different case from the link target.

Comment: Yep, thank you, I saw that too. I was hoping there was some undocumented way. Or perhaps I could ask for this feature to be added to org mode (can't implement it myself).